# Changing the appearance of messages in the Messaging app on Droid RAZR Maxx?

Tags: sms, motorola-droid, customization

I was just wondering if there was any (easy) way to change the appearance of the native messaging app on Droid RAZR Maxx - it doesn't need to be fancy, just resetting it to the default Android 2.3 style would be nice. Ideally, I'd like to keep the same app (so, in other words, without using GoSMS, Handcent, etc.).

If there isn't an easy way to do this, is it possible to do with a rooted Droid RAZR Maxx? If so, could anyone point me towards a tutorial? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is probably to use a third party messaging app such as [Handcent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) or [Go SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms). Changing the default app itself probably needs rooting and some difficult mangling.

Please bear in mind that I have not tested these apps, and cannot say if they work well or not.

Comment: -1 because user asked specifically not to use third party apps, and you answer exactly with the examples given by the asker!